# Site is too wide on mobile

Tags: html, css

The site I created makes an unnecessary large width on the page. The page is supposed to fit to the screen of a mobile phone. But I seem to have to scroll to the right for nothing. This is the site: https://gwenlotest.000webhostapp.com/index.html

it works perfectly on big screens but as soon as I open the site on mobile websites I have to scroll to get to the burger menu and I don't understand why.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused because of the elements that animate from the right. Look into putting them in another `div` that wraps these elements. The `div` will should have 100% width.

As you might notice, as you scroll down, when the elements animate from the right edge of the screen, the right *extension* disappears.

Comment: This is actually the right reason. I'm using scroll reveal, and I'm using the parameter that it should reveal from 300px. This is the reason. If I take away that the site loads without a h-scroll

Comment: But when I scroll down (after I've fixed the issue) and I get to the part where there is icons and text underneath the about us section the site changes back to a wide site for some reason where I can scroll in the horizontal direction?

Comment: Mine doesn't do that. It seems fixed right now. What browser are you using? I will try it out with that browser.

Comment: I'm using samsung browser, When I get past "subjects we offer" it changes to the width of something greater than the screen

Comment: I found the error by the way. My tool-tip text which is hidden was 400px wide.

Answer (score 2):

Add shrink-to-fit=no to your meta name="viewport" so it should be in the form

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

i think that should fix the issue.

Comment: This does not fix the issue